# google closure compiler and history API

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, html5-history

I have this code that I'm putting through the GCC in advanced compilation mode:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) { .... }
```

I get this message:

```
 JSC_WRONG_ARGUMENT_COUNT: Function Window.prototype.addEventListener: called 
 with 2 argument(s). Function requires at least 3 argument(s) and no more than
 3 argument(s). at line 3601 character 0
 window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
```

What do I need to change in my code to make it pass without warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the useCapture variable of addEventListener.

This is probably what you want:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {...}, false);
```